# Git: ftp is not a command

Tags: git, git-ftp

I'm trying to use the git-ftp on Windows 10. I've tried all steps on [this page](https://www.codingsips.com/install-configure-git-ftp-windows/).

It suggests to write these commands on `git bash`:

```
cd /d/"Program Files"/Git
git clone https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp git-ftp.git
cd git-ftp.git && chmod +x git-ftp
cp /d/"Program Files"/Git/git-ftp.git/git-ftp /d/"Program Files"/Git/bin/git-ftp
```

And write these commands in the project folder to cmd:

```
git config git-ftp.url ftp://ftp.yourdomain.com/public_html/whatever_path
git config git-ftp.user ftp_username
git config git-ftp.password ftp_password
git add .
git commit -m "files changes"
git ftp init
```

But when I try to write this code:

```
git ftp init
```

It just give me this error:

```
git: 'ftp' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

I don't know what am I missing.

**EDIT**:

I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/pull/581) on github.

Comment: Is your Windows `git` defined in `C:\Program Files\Git` or perhaps you are picking up a different `git` from a different folder?

Comment: My git is defined in D:\Program Files\Git but I wrote it like that. The text above is only for sample

Comment: Ok so what you show in your question isn't really what you entered? Like `cd /c/"Program Files"/Git`...? You actually wrote `cd /d/"Program Files"/Git`... etc? You should show what you did (edit your question to do so).

Comment: I've written the question as sample. Ok, I'm editing it

Comment: You still have a `/c/...` in there. Is that what you executed or did you forget to edit that one?

Comment: I have updated my answer to reference the correct path (D:\...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [README for `git-ftp/git-ftp`](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) includes:

> Windows and OS X: I am very limited in testing on Windows and OS X. Thanks for helping me out fixing bugs on these platforms.

Still, on Windows, you can simply copy the `git-ftp` in D:\Program Files\Git\bin (you don't even have to be in a bash): any `git-xxx` file which is in the `%PATH%` would be executed by `git xxx`

Check first in a regular CMD (with the appropriate PATH) if `git ftp` is recognized. (Assuming `D:\Program Files\Git\bin` is in your `%PATH%`)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right way. We neeed to add the git-ftp file's path to system path's